# JavaScript scroll over element works in Chrome but not in IE11

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, internet-explorer, kendo-grid

I'm writing an e2e test with selenium C#

I need to scroll to the bottom of a kendo-grid scrollbar element (scrolling any other element like grid body does not seem to work). The code that does that is:

```
$('div.k-scrollbar-vertical')[0].scrollTo(0,12000)
```

Works fine in Chrome console and via `IJavaScriptExecutor` in C#, but trying it in IE11 raises an error:

`Object doesn't support property or method 'scrollTo'`

Is there any way I can make it compatible to both browsers or any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the more supported mechanism?

```
const o = document.querySelector('div.k-scrollbar-vertical')
o.scrollTop = o.scrollHeight
```

And if `const` is not supported in your version, you can use `var`

Comment: Mostly works, however only in form like this: `js.ExecuteScript("document.querySelector('div.k-scrollbar-vertical').scrollTop=document.querySelector('div.k-scrollbar-vertical').scrollHeight;");`

The version:

`js.ExecuteScript("var bar = document.querySelector('div.k-scrollbar-vertical');" +
"bar.scrollTop = bar.scrollHeight;");`

doesn't work, `bar.scrollHeight` throws a null reference for some reason. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure what `js` is. But it is very much possible your js is executing before the page has actually loaded, therefore there's no `div.k-scrollbar-vertical` yet!

Comment: Sorry, missed that. `js` is a C# `IJavascriptExecutor` instance. You're probably right, I added a wait for scrollbar visibility and it worked. Thanks!